# Concating Optional Strings

Tags: c#

I am using concat to join 2 strings in my method, but I am facing a situation that If  String A/B is null, instead of concating with String A/B, it should be empty. like this

```
var message = "ABC" + Null;
```

So what I am looking for is that `message = ""` instead of `ABC`

How can I do that in C#

Comment: Well, don't use concatenation, because that's not how it works. Are you joining multiple values and you want the result to be null if any of the values is null? If so just add a check that all the values are not null first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use a simple `if`:

```cs
var message = string.Empty;

if (a != null && b != null)
{
    message = a + b;
}
```

Or, a one liner:

```cs
var message = (a == null || b == null) ? string.Empty : a + b;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
string ConcatIfNotNull(string a, string b)
{
    if (a == null || b == null)
        return "";
    else
        return a + b;
}
```